# Spring LockRegistry Issue with INT_LOCK

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am using JDBC lock registry but getting INT_LOCK table not being present issue:

```
@Bean
    DefaultLockRepository defaultLockRepository(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        DefaultLockRepository repository = new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
        repository.setRegion(this.region);
        repository.setTimeToLive(60 * 5000);
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    JdbcLockRegistry jdbcLockRegistry(LockRepository lockRepository) {
        return new JdbcLockRegistry(lockRepository);
    }
```

**Error Log:**

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM INT_LOCK WHERE REGION=? AND LOCK_KEY=? AND CREATED_DATE

```
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:599) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:816) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:877) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:887) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.DefaultLockRepository.deleteExpired(DefaultLockRepository.java:158) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.DefaultLockRepository.acquire(DefaultLockRepository.java:138) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M5.jar:5.0.0.M5]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.acquire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.JdbcLockRegistry$JdbcLock.doLock(JdbcLockRegistry.java:224) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.JdbcLockRegistry$JdbcLock.tryLock(JdbcLockRegistry.java:202) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
... 87 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or vie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the table(s) to the database to use the lock registry. The schemas for various SI components are in the spring-integration-jdbc jar.

You can also see them on GitHub [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/v5.3.0.RELEASE/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc) - make sure you use the version corresponding to your jar.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you. What is the significance of these tables, couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: They are for message stores, metadata store, and lock registry - briefly discussed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc).

Comment: @GaryRussell ,  Is it possible to utilize only the INT_LOCK table without including the rest? at the moment i only have use for the lock table and am not utilizing the other tables.

Comment: Yes; you only need to create the table(s) that you use.